# Find and replace, field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, vbscript

Can someone show me a very simple find and replace in field calculator for just one or two characters in a field based hyperlink?

Comment: Is what you are trying to replace unique within the string? Or could there be duplicates in the same string?

Comment: Maybe an alternative to field calculator: Click Table Options and click Find & Replace.

Comment: You should try to do more of your own research before posting a question -- this is easily found in help or google.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly, you might try something like the replace() function:

#### VBS

```
replace([FieldName], "Old Value", "New Value")
```

#### Python

```
!FieldName!.replace("Old Value", "New Value")
```

Here is a link to the ESRI support page for it:
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/20119

Comment: Or !FieldName!.replace("Old Value", "New Value"). Don't forget to select the python parser.